# Trouble returning API response leveraging fetch

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

Been working on a script to execute in Google Apps Scripts to pull some data from an external API and post that information into a Google Sheet. I have a script that works client side (running from the console in chrome) that is able to leverage promises and return HTTP responses correctly to execute more code on.

However, in Apps Scripts I cannot figure out how to return a native JSON object representation from the API. In normal JS, I would return the `.json()` method of the response and would be good to go. Since Apps Script is essentially executing a `.gs` file they have different classes and methods that are not specific to JS. This help doc https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external provides the below example for working with JSON

```
var json = response.getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(json);
Logger.log(data.title);
```

If I try to leverage that `getContextText()` method by itself I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` error. If I combine it with `JSON.parse` like `return JSON.parse(response.getContentText());` I get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token M in JSON at position 0`. Am I missing something wildly obvious? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Additionally, happy to provide more specifics from my script as well.

**EDIT**

Below is a snippet of script that works client side.

```
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  
  const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': "Basic" + ' ' + gongCreds,
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'Content-Type': "application/json"
  },
  body: gongRequestBody,
});
 
  return response.json(); 
}
```

Here is the returned promise object data that I want to leverage for future execution

```
[[PromiseResult]]: Object
records: {totalRecords: 1, currentPageSize: 1, currentPageNumber: 0}
requestId: "6w83fpcbo5ka2evast7"
usersDetailedActivities: Array(1)
0:
userDailyActivityStats: Array(1)
0:
callsAsHost: []
callsAttended: (6) ["432806286570218902", "1825323793748204011", "3193437184015561879", "4172384470445855263", "5128172192322468435", "5808052479141116583"]
callsCommentsGiven: []
callsCommentsReceived: []
callsGaveFeedback: []
callsMarkedAsFeedbackGiven: []
callsMarkedAsFeedbackReceived: []
callsReceivedFeedback: []
callsRequestedFeedback: []
callsScorecardsFilled: []
callsScorecardsReceived: []
callsSharedExternally: []
callsSharedInternally: []
fromDate: "2021-01-20T05:00:00Z"
othersCallsListenedTo: (2) ["3401282086024720458", "8098199458721511977"]
```

Comment: What is the content of `response.getContentText();`? According to the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token M in JSON at position 0` error, it is not a JSON as it starts with `M`.

Comment: json must always start with opening brace {

Comment: @zhulien -- The API server returns a JSON object. For context in my code I am leveraging promises. Happy to share the specifics

Comment: In your situation, the value of `response.getContentText()` is the result you expected? And, for example, can you provide the sample script of `I have a script that works client side`?

Comment: @DaveThompson Please, post an edit to your question with the value returned by `response.getContentText()`. Also, what Tanaike said.

Comment: @zhulien Edited and added the returned promise object

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. At first, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your updated question, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

When your following Javascript is converted to Google Apps Script,

```
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  
  const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': "Basic" + ' ' + gongCreds,
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'Content-Type': "application/json"
  },
  body: gongRequestBody,
});
 
  return response.json(); 
}
```

it becomes as follows.

```
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': "Basic" + ' ' + gongCreds,
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
  },
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
  contentType: "application/json",
  payload: gongRequestBody,
});
console.log(response.getContentText())
// I think that if above request works and the returned value is the correct value you expected, you can use console.log(JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).title)
```

But, there are several important points.

1. From your script, I cannot see the value of `gongRequestBody`. When `'Content-Type': "application/json"` is used, `JSON.stringify()` is required to be used for the JSON object. So if `gongRequestBody` is the JSON object, please convert it to the string using `JSON.stringify()`.
2. From your question, I cannot see your script for requesting to the URL. So I cannot point out the modification points of your script even when your script has the modification points.
3. I asked to show the sample value of `response.getContentText()` in your Google Apps Script. But unfortunately, I cannot find the sample value of it. So when you use `console.log(JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).title)` to the above sample script of Google Apps Script and an error occurs, can you provide the sample value of `console.log(response.getContentText())`? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that your Javascript works and the variables of `gongCreds`, `gongCreds` and `gongRequestBody` are the valid values for requesting to your URL. Please be careful this. So when above sample script didn't work as you expected, can you provide the sample value of `console.log(response.getContentText())`? By this, I would like to confirm your situation.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)